# Cannot build docker image after run Minikube build-env

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I'm using Minikube in Windows 10 and I'd like to use locally built Docker images instead of images hosted in a registry, so, according [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@maumribeiro/running-your-own-docker-images-in-minikube-for-windows-ea7383d931f6), I have to run next commands:

Use local kubernetes and images:

```
> minikube docker-env
```

The output is:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> minikube docker-env
$Env:DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY = "1"
$Env:DOCKER_HOST = "tcp://10.98.38.126:2376"
$Env:DOCKER_CERT_PATH = "C:\Users\MyUser\.minikube\certs"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# & minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression
```

To configure the shell, run this:

```
> & minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression
```

After that, I need to build a new image:

```
PS D:\repos\test> docker build -t miImage:v1 .
```

And I have next error:

```
PS D:\repos\test> docker build -t miImage:v1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   8.62MB
Step 1/10 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
Get https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

This is error is thrown since I configured it to use local images, is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Is your connection behind a proxy? If so, you may need to configure it. If you are using Docker for WIndows go to the settings and configure the proxy connection. Also there is chance that you are facing a DNS problem. You may try the following: go to control panel -> network center -> change adapter settings -> right-click properties on the VM used by minikube -> edit TCP ipv4 with a DNS like 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

Comment: I forgot to say it, but you can actually try restarting docker.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like the machine that you're using to build is unable to reach https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/ to confirm that, try to send a simple GET to the URL

```
wget https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/
```

if that's the problem, you can use a different machine to pull the image, then save it to a file and load it on the target machine.

```
#on a machine connected to internet 
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2
docker save mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 > dotnetsdk2_2.tar
# download the file
# on the target machine 
docker load < dotnetsdk2_2.tar
```

then your build should work without a problem using the local version of the image.

Comment: Your answer has all sense in the world. Right now minikube has crashed (it happens all the time), let me start again services and I'll try your answer. Thx